# Reading data from XML into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I've an XML file, in which I'm saving temporary data(index & name of columns) as given below:

```
-<NewDataSet> 
    -<USERROWCOL> 
          <COL>2</COL> 
          <Name>Name</Name> 
     </USERROWCOL> 
    -<USERROWCOL> 
          <COL>8</COL> 
          <Name>PDC</Name> 
     </USERROWCOL>
 <NewDataSet>
```

I want to read all `COL`s in an array using C# like it will be an array( `{2, 8}` ). Can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a LINQ to XML Version:

```
string[] arr = XDocument.Load(@"C:\xxx.xml").Descendants("Name")
                        .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

This will give all the `Name` element from the document.

Answer (score 8):

LINQ to XML makes this very easy:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
var array = document.Descendants("COL").Select(x => (int) x).ToArray();
```

That's assuming you just want *every* `COL` element in the document, and every element's value will be an integer.